# Kafka fetch max bytes doesn't work as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic worth 1 GB of messages. A. Kafka consumer decides to consume these messages. What could I do to prohibit the consumer from consuming all messages at once? I tried to set the

`fetch.max.bytes` on the broker

to 30 MB to allow only 30 MB of messages in each poll. The broker doesn't seem to honor that and tries to give all messages at once to the consumer causing Consumer out of memory error. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kafka configurations can be quite overwhelming. Typically in Kafka, multiple configurations can work together to achieve a result. This brings flexibility, but flexibility comes with a price.

From the documentation of `fetch.max.bytes`:

> Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress.

Only on the consumer side, there are more configurations to consider for bounding the consumer memory usage, including:

- `max.poll.records`: limits the number of records retrieved in a single call to poll. Default is 500.
- `max.partition.fetch.bytes`: limits the number of bytes fetched per partition. This should not be a problem as the default is 1MB.

As per the information in [KIP-81](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-81%3A+Bound+Fetch+memory+usage+in+the+consumer), the memory usage in practice should be something like `min(num brokers * max.fetch.bytes,  max.partition.fetch.bytes * num_partitions)`.

Also, in the same KIP:

> The consumer (Fetcher) delays decompression until the records are returned to the user, but because of max.poll.records, it may end up holding onto the decompressed data from a single partition for a few iterations.

I'd suggest you to also tune these parameters and hopefully this will get you into the desired state.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried "max.partition.fetch.bytes", which works well, however, it drops messages that are below that number. My max message size on Kafka is 5 MB. When I set the max.partition.fetch.bytes to 5 MB I don't get anything back. Not sure if it's a Kafka broker memory issue or it's something I need to tweak

Comment: Yes, it's a restriction. `max.partition.fetch.bytes` must always be greater than `max.message.bytes` (broker config). Otherwise, the consumer may not be able to consume all messages.

Comment: What happens when I have a cluster of 3 brokers and I set the max.partition.fetch.bytes. ? I am seeing weird responses. Sometimes partitions from 2 brokers are read, while sometimes only 1 broker is read. It doesn't provide all partitions from all 3 brokers. Because of this the lag builds up as I get less than expected data back from the broker.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the num brokers might affect the memory usage, but depending on the exact behavior observed it could also be related to the number of partitions or session timeout config. Since this is a follow-up question with a specific issue, I’d strongly suggest you post it as a separate new question and make sure to specify the available heap memory, number of brokers, topics, partitions, consumer instances and and session timeout, along with any logs and observed errors or behaviors.

Comment: Using max.fetch.bytes in node-kafka as seemingly the only way to throttle kafka led me to run away errors, described here: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/1208. I hit this with max fetch bytes of 50k, with messages that are about 2k each.