# Kafka and Event Streaming On Client Side?

Tags: apache-kafka

I need to consume messages from a event source (represented as a single Kafka topic) producing about 50k to 250k events per second. It only provides a single partition and the ping is quite high (90-100ms).

As far as I have learned by reading the Kafka client code, during polling a fetch request is issued and once the response is fully read, the events/messages are parsed and deserialized and once enough events/messages are available consumer.poll() will provide the subset to the calling application.

In my case this makes the whole thing not worth while. The best throughput I achieve with about 2s duration per fetch request (about 2.5MB fetch.max.bytes). Smaller fetch durations will increase the idle time (time the consumer does not receive any bytes) between last byte of previous response, parsing, deserialization and sending next request and waiting for the first byte of the next request's response.

Using a fetch duration of about 2s results in a max latency of 2s which is highly undesirable. What I would like to see is while receiving the fetch response, that the messages transmitted are already available to the consumer as soon as a individual message is fully transmitted.

Since every message has an individual id and the messages are send in a particular order while only a single consumer (+thread) for a single partition is active, it is not a problem to suppress retransmitted messages in case a fetch response is aborted / fails and its messages were partially processed and later on retransmitted.

So the big question is, if the Kafka client provides a possibility to consume messages from a not-yet completed fetch response.

Comment: To clarify, your "event source"  with one partition is a Kafka topic, or not?

Comment: It is a single Kafka topic indeed. I modified the question to clarify it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: And you are using Java code? Have you considered using other libraries like librdkafka based solutions for lower-level access to the network requests?

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty large amount of messages coming in through a single partition.  Since you can't control anything on the Kafka server, the best you can do is configure your client to be as efficient as possible, assuming you have access to Kafka client configuration parameters.  You didn't mention anything about needing to consume the messages as fast as they're generated, so I'm assuming you don't need that.  Also I didn't see any info about average message size, how much message sizes vary, but unless those are crazy values, the suggestions below should help.

The first thing you need to do is set `max.poll.records` on the client side to a smallish number, say, start with 10000, and see how much throughput that gets you.  Make sure to consume without doing anything with the messages, just dump them on the floor, and then call `poll()` again.  This is just to benchmark how much performance you can get with your fixed server setup.  Then, increase or decrease that number depending on if you need better throughput or latency. You should be able to get a best scenario after playing with this for a while.

After having done the above, the next step is to change your code so it dumps all received messages to an internal in-memory queue, and then call `poll()` again.  This is especially important if processing of each message requires DB access, hitting external APIs, etc.  If you take even 100ms to process 1K messages, that can reduce your performance in half in your case (100ms to poll/receive, and then another 100ms to process the messages received before you start the next `poll()`)

Without having access to Kafka configuration parameters on the server side, I believe the above should get you pretty close to an optimal throughput for your configuration.

Feel free to post more details in your question, and I'd be happy to update my answer if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with such a high throughput, this is what community recommendations for number of partitions on a source topic. And it is worth considering all these factors when choosing the number of partitions.

• What is the throughput you expect to achieve for the topic?

• What is the maximum throughput you expect to achieve when
consuming from a single partition?

• If you are sending messages to partitions based on keys,
adding partitions later can be very challenging, so calculate
throughput based on your expected future usage, not the current
usage.

• Consider the number of partitions you will place on each
broker and available diskspace and network bandwidth per
broker.

So if you want to be able to write and read 1 GB/sec from a topic, and each consumer can only process 50 MB/s, then you need at least 20 partitions. This way, you can have 20 consumers reading from the topic and achieve 1 GB/sec.

Also,

Regarding the fetch.max.bytes, I am sure you have already had a glance on this one [Kafka fetch max bytes doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067624/kafka-fetch-max-bytes-doesnt-work-as-expected).

Comment: I can not change that number of partitions. This is a 3rd party offering. By reading the linked stackoverflow question, it still points to the idea that I have to wait for the fetch request to complete before seeing the first event. Is there a mechanism or strategy that I can use to stream events as soon as they can be extracted from an incomplete fetch response? This unnecessary latency really is a bummer. I do not care for inconsistencies and the network layer already compensates for most of the related issues.